# iOS get error by creating a pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation

i want to create a pdf file, but i get 2 errors:

```
<Error>: CGDataConsumerCreateWithFilename: failed to open `/test.pdf' for writing:   Operation not permitted. deflateEnd: error -3: (null).
```

and this one

```
<Error>: CGPDFContextCreate: failed to create PDF context delegate.
```

I compute the path in the controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    documentName = @"test.pdf";
    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFileName];

    PDFRenderer *pdf = [[PDFRenderer alloc]initWithFileName:documentName];
    [pdf renderPDF];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and in the render class I call the

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(documentName, CGRectZero, nil);
```

function and I get the errors.

**How I fix that error?**

Comment: You should call `[super viewDidLoad];` first, not last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to a relative path, try to change it into

```
PDFRenderer *pdf = [[PDFRenderer alloc]initWithFileName:pdfFileName];
```

i.e. the absolute path in the documents directory.

If you look at the error message, you will see that the file is being attempted to be written in the root directory.

Comment: Good catch. I overlooked that the wrong variable was passed to the renderer.