# Writing permission for generated pdf : swift on 11.3 only

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am getting error while generating pdf on iOS 11.3. It's working fine with iOS 11.2.

```
CGDataConsumerCreateWithFilename: failed to open `/note.pdf' for writing: Operation not permitted.
deflateEnd: error -3: (null).
```

Pdf is generated well but when I try to access it to upload, it generates error. Code for the same is :

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

let fileURL:URL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("note.pdf")

do {
   try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: fileURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
   NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile((fileURL.path as NSString).lastPathComponent as String?, CGRectZero, nil);
```

The last line generates error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS get error by creating a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126818/ios-get-error-by-creating-a-pdf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502181/where-to-store-a-created-pdf-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126818/ios-get-error-by-creating-a-pdf  please search extensively before posting a question

Comment: before posting the comment please read the question. i am facing issue on 11.3 . its working fine at 11.2

Comment: uninstall the application and reinstall the application ..try  renaming your file

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the file in root directory , You can not do this, try this

```
 let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

            let fileURL:URL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("note.pdf")

            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: fileURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
            }

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileURL.appendingPathComponent("note.pdf").path, CGRect.zero, nil);
```

> Which will get and according to what you are doing you will create a
>   folder `note.pdf` and then save the file `note.pdf` inside it